# Is there a global function in python to find the maximum of a 2d array based on a specified dimension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, max

Example:

```
input=[(10,1),(2,3),(6,2)]
output= 3
```

(since the maximum of the 2nd dimension is 3, `3` is returned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max` with `key` parameter.

```
input=[(10,1),(2,3),(6,2)]
output=max(input,key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
# 3
```

---

You can use `itemgetter`(If you don't prefer using `lambda`)

```
from operator import itemgetter
output=max(input,key=itemgetter(1))[1]
# 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy to do exactly this

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(input)
print(a[: , 1].max())
```

Comment: Ohh.. I didn`t understand that this is the desired output. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that function there are or no. But look at this:

```py
my_items = [(10,1),(2,3),(6,2)]

my_items.sort(key=lambda e: e[0])

print (my_items[0])
```

[execute](http://tpcg.io/ONwTNoa8)